# What does the red text in variable watches in Code::Blocks mean? Does that mean the variable is not declared?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have been creating a function that returns the address of a variable in `main` function. It caused an error and I know that it could not return the address, because since `main` has got out to another function the variables got deleted or de-allocated. I think so.

I tried to test that out and see it in the debugger. In the image below I ran into the debug mode and that's what I get. This image shows the point at where the debug ends after "stepping into" the `test` function, and it returned to `main` function.

In the variables watches I see red text. Does that mean that the variable is still declared?

[image: Screenshot 101]

Example Code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int *test(int o)
{
    return &o;
    printf("-----");
}

int main()
{
    int p = 10;
    printf("-----");
    int *y = test(p);
    printf("-----");
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in the question itself, don't post images of code.

Comment: done i have pasted the code

Comment: I don't use Code Blocks, but it's common for a visual debugger to change the color of variables and such to indicate that they have changed.

Comment: You looked into the documentation, didn't you? What did it say, and why does that not help you?

Answer (score 0):

When I compiled your code, gcc threw a warning:

```
$ gcc -o /tmp/test /tmp/test.c
/tmp/test.c: In function ‘test’:
/tmp/test.c:5:17: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    5 |         return (&o);
      |                ~^~~
```

The parameter `o` is local to `test()` so you shouldn't try to send it outside that function.

Secondly, your `printf()` in `test()` is *after* the `return`, so will never get executed.

Thirdly, you don't specify what error was shown by the debugger so we can't really help you with that.

Finally, your code outputs a total of 10 "-" characters, so you're not actually able to see what's going on with your variables.

Comment: This is not an answer to the actual question, why the debugger shows the variables in red.